# android i want to add searchview in actionbar but not got it

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

i have a layout in which on the title bar i have option button and back button which work fine now i want to add searchview in the action bar but i dont know how to do this i am new in android so please help me to solve my problem.

this is my activity code.

```
    public class Thrd extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_thrd);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("3rd page");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#20a780"));
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_Exit:
                openExit();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
    private void openExit() {

    }
}
```

this is manu res file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_Exit"
    android:title="@string/action_Exit"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
```

this is string.xml file

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">QDAS</string>

<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_Exit">Exit</string>

<string name="title_activity_secnd">Secnd</string>
<string name="title_activity_thrd">Thrd</string>

<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
```

i have title bar like as
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) it shows step by step how to add search functionality.